# write a gradle script that saves all the dependency into the ${projectDir}/lib folder

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build

So I have a gradle script which gets all its dependencies from the following repository

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repository.paychex.com:8081/artifactory/repo1-cache' }



          ivy   { url 'http://repository.paychex.com:8081/artifactory/repo1 cache' 
            layout 'pattern', {
              artifact '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]/[module]-[revision].jar' 
            }
          }
mavenlocal()

}
```

so when I run a customized gradle task which i wrote as

```
task showMeCache << {
  configurations.compile.each { println it }
}
```

It will show that my jars are being saved locally on

C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1***

I want to write a gradle task that will put all the dependencies for a given project into something like a ${projectDir}/lib folder instead of the default location provided by gradle. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [Copy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task for that purpose:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'lib'
}
```

Keep in mind that would still download and use the resolved dependencies from the Gradle cache.

Comment: Two things: **1.** probably better use `configurations.runtime` if you want to use these libs at runtime and somewhen in the future use runtime dependencies. **2.** probably better use `type: Sync` as it will also remove stale libs that you do not reference anymore. `type: Copy` will just copy the current ones into the `lib` dir, leaving all present files untouched or overwritten.

Comment: oh that just worked like a breeze my man. I will consider your other points as well.